# Flutter: Picking images as jpg/png instead of heic on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, jpeg, imagepicker, heic

How can I pick images directly as jpg or png on iOS?
If this feature isn't available: How can I convert it very fast and don't have to wait a long time?

Edit: I want to prevent picking .heic because I have to send it to an server, which handles jpg and png and not .heic

Comment: Have you tried https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker and picking PNG/JPG images instead of using image picker?

Comment: Am I able to pick only from gallery?

Comment: this pub should allow you to pick from multiple directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Mohammad Assad Arshad!
It can be solved by  pub.dev/packages/file_picker.

An additional explanation:

- https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker allows you to pick files/images etc. and the file type of images is .jpg
- https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker allows you to pick images too, **but** takes the original file format; e.g. .heic, .jpg, .png

Comment: does file converts the heic to jpg or it just skips heic image?

Comment: I didn't try it in the last time, but in my opinion the images get converted

Comment: unfortunately the multi_image_picker is discontinued. do you have an other alternative where I can pick *.heic with except wechat_asset_picker?

Comment: @Ayrix Can use ImagePicker flutter library, they have multiple images pickers now 
https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker/versions

Answer (score 3):

i select images with filepicker https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

```
FilePickerResult result;
try {
  result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
    type: FileType.custom,
    allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'heic', 'pdf'],
  );
} catch (e) {
  print('Exep: ****${e}***');
}
```

now you can check the extention of the file, use the package path.dart as p and package https://pub.dev/packages/heic_to_jpg to convert image to jpeg

```
 File file = File(result.files.first.path);
  String fileExtension = p.extension(file.path).replaceAll('.', '');
  if (fileExtension == 'heic') {
    print('convert to jpeg');
    String jpegPath = await HeicToJpg.convert(file.path);
    file = File(jpegPath);
    fileExtension = 'jpeg';
  }
```

do not forget do the same if you use imagePicker with source camera.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [multi_image_picker 4.6.7](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker) to pick image in iOS for HEIC images.

Comment: I want to prevent picking heic, like I’m telling in the title :/