# How to access original file path using "image_picker" plugin for Flutter after taking a picture?

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm trying to take a photo with my iPhone and access the original file (*.HEIC if picture is taken by an iPhone) afterwards using the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) version 0.8.2 plugin in Flutter.

Below my problem:

```
final XFile photo = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
                    print(photo.path);
```

The print result shows:
`flutter: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/660C28A9-9167-417B-8FCC-F7CC234F027C/tmp/image_picker_9B836DE1-A90D-4270-9151-1BD420D24DCA-9388-0000069CA5F4337B.jpg`

which is not the path of the original File I want to access to. This seems more to be the cached image path.
But what I am actually expecting is the path of the *.HEIC file.

Anyone who could help me here?

Thanks!

Comment: May be this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62259764 will be useful

Comment: @VasilyAvilov Thanks for you reply but the suggested plugin "multi_image_picker" got discontinued. Do you still think it's a good Idea to use that?

Comment: did you reall test on a physical device, or in the simulator?

Comment: @Ayrix I see it was published last time May 15, 2021. I think it is not so far await and there is no reason why it will not work. Moreover in answer at the link there is second file_picker package.

Comment: @Herbert Poul  yes I‘ve tried on a physical device :)

Comment: @Vasiliy Avilov - yes you are right that the last update was released recently and I’m sure that it will work but I was more worried about the future :) but thanks anyway for your efforts